# Double summation index problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I often meet the following situation:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0} ^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0} ^n f(k)g(n-k)=\sum\limits_{p=0} ^\infty \sum\limits_{q=0}^\infty f(p)g(q)$$

While intuitively this is very clear to me, I'm having problems to rigorously prove this. Could somebody please help me out?

So far my friends and I have come up with the map: $(n,k) \rightarrow (q,p) \text{ with } k\leq n$ where $q(n)=n-k$ and $p(n)=q+n=k$ Therefore we only need to prove  bijection.

Thanks

EDIT: The original problem was motivated by:

$$e^{(L_A+L_B)}=\sum\limits_{n=0} ^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0} ^n \frac{1}{k! (n-k)!} L_1^k  L_2^{n-k}=\sum\limits_{p=0} ^\infty \sum\limits_{q=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p! q!} L_1^p L_2^q=$$

where $L_A$ and $L_B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is a Banach space. However, I encountered the same problem when dealing with double Fourier transforms

Comment: You need some conditions for the rearrangement to be valid (absolute convergence or non-negativity for example). In what setting should the rigorous proof be? Both series absolutely convergent, one absolutely convergent and the other conditionally, both sequences non-negative?

Comment: I think the series is undoubtedly absolutely convergent, but I'm not sure about the other conditions.

Comment: Your motivating example is absolutely convergent. The conditions are alternative, any one of them suffices. The non-negativity is relevant only for real sequences, so not pertinent here.

Comment: Could you please develop a simple proof? Thanks

Comment: Do you know the proof for the Cauchy product formula of two absolutely convergent real (or complex) series? The same proof works for Banach spaces, one just has to replace the absolute value with the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not the convergence that bothers you, but the description of the same set in two different ways. Draw a figure of ${\mathbb N}_{\geq0}\times {\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$, and everything becomes obvious. Anyway, here is a formal proof (all letters denote nonnegative integers):

For given $n\geq0$ one has
$$\{(k,n-k)\>|\>0\leq k\leq n\}=\{(p,q)\>|\>p\geq0, \ q\geq 0, \ p+q=n\}\ .$$
It follows that
$$\eqalign{\{(k,n-k)\>|\>n\geq0, \ 0\leq k\leq n\}
&=\bigcup_{n\geq0}\{(p,q)\>|\>p\geq0, \ q\geq 0, \ p+q=n\}\cr
&=\{(p,q)\>|\>p\geq0, \ q\geq 0\}\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$Completely ignoring matters of convergence, and using notations from Dijkstra et al. (see, e.g., [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) for details), I would prove this equality as follows (I'm taking baby steps here):

$$\calc
\langle + n,k : 0 \leq k \leq n : f(k) \times g(n-k) \rangle
\calcop{=}{logic: introduce name $\;q\;$ using one-point rule}
\langle + n,k,q : q = n - k \land 0 \leq k \leq n : f(k) \times g(q) \rangle
\calcop{=}{arithmetic}
\langle + n,k,q : n = q - k \land 0 \leq k \leq n : f(k) \times g(q) \rangle
\calcop{=}{logic: substitute $\;n\;$ using one-point rule}
\langle + k,q : 0 \leq k \leq q - k : f(k) \times g(q) \rangle
\calcop{=}{arithmetic: simplify}
\langle + k,q : 0 \leq k \land 0 \leq q : f(k) \times g(q) \rangle
\endcalc$$

Answer (score -1):

Let us consider the term $f(p)g(q)$, where $p$, $q$ are fixed. The summation on the left-hand side contains the term $f(p)g(q)$ ($k=p$, and $n=p+q$). Moreover, the term appears only once in this summation. This implies the equality.

Comment: Not so easy. Do you know Riemann's rearrangement theorem? If the convergence is not absolute, reordering can change the sum.

Comment: D.J.Zhang, thanks that make sense! While you proved every term in the second sum is contained in the first one, it's still necessary to prove viceversa, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.